# group/ungroup rows from cel function in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for an excel function that permits to group (or ungroup) some rows if a condition is met.

To be more specific let me make an example. 
I am interested in hiding some rows if a given cell contains the string "No".

So in my idea, I am thinking about something like:

```
=IF(B2="No";<HIDE_rows_from_4_to_5>;<do_nothing>)
```

Is it feasible? Any idea or comment?

Comment: Not in a worksheet function, no. In VBA you'd use the [Range.Hidden property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hidden)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was not able to find a function for this command. Probably, as reported in the comment, this task cannot be done with a function.

Therefore, I solve it using VBA and the following command:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C").Hidden = True
```